# How to add the label of a Primefaces chart?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF line chart that uses PrimeFaces. I want to add labels to both x-axis & y-axis eg Year & Populations. I have used  showLabel:true but its not working.The is code,

```
   <p:lineChart id="chart" value="#{chartBean.linearModel}" xaxisAngle="-90">
       <f:convertDateTime pattern="d-M-yyyy"/>
    </p:lineChart>


function phaseChartExt() {
     this.cfg.axes = {
              xaxis: {
                  renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                  rendererOptions: { tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer },
                  tickOptions: {
                      showLabel:true,
                      showGridline: true,
                      formatString: '%H:%M',
                      angle: -90                        
                 }         
             }
             yaxis: {
                 renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                 rendererOptions: { tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer },
                 tickOptions: {
                     showLabel:true,
                     showGridline: true,
                     formatString: '%H:%M',
                     angle: -90                        
                }         
    }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

xaxisLabel="Year" yaxisLabel="Populations"

```
 <p:lineChart id="chart" value="#{chartBean.linearModel}" xaxisAngle="-90" xaxisLabel="Year" yaxisLabel="Populations">
       <f:convertDateTime pattern="d-M-yyyy"/>
    </p:lineChart>
```